# Dataloader via Command Line cannot export out fields like Id and formula fields

Tags: data-loader, commandline, dataloader-batch

I am currently using a batch script I wrote up to export out multiple standard/custom objects out **daily** so I need to use Dataloader Command Line to accomplish my job.

However I noticed that Dataloader Command Line is **NOT** able to export out **ID** or even **formula fields** whereas Dataloader via UI can.

Is there a workaround I can do to get around this issue?

Below is the sample of my process-conf.xml for anyone who would like to reproduce this issue

```
<bean id="csvBookingExtractProcess"
      class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
      singleton="false">
  <description>csvBookingExtract job gets account info from salesforce and saves info into a CSV file."</description>
    <property name="name" value="csvBookingExtract"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\Users\..\sfdcSoapTrace.log"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://ap4.salesforce.com"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="username"/>
            <!--password value should be encrypted password+securitytoken -->
            <entry key="sfdc.password" value="encrypted password+Securitytoken"/>
            <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="C:\Users\..\delphiKey"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="2000"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Booking__c"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="2000"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="C:\Users\..\bookingExtractMap_Delphi.sdl"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
            <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="csvWrite"/>

            <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.readUTF8" value="true"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.writeBatchSize" value="2000"/>
            <!--Change values below-->
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id, Name, Booking_Formula__c FROM Booking__c LIMIT 10 "/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\..\booking_ddmmyy.csv"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the Mapping file with extension .sdl was not fully updated.
Even for exporting purposes, the mapping file must have all the fields mapped like :

```
#Mapping values
#Mon Feb 03 17:47:18 SGT 2020
id=id
LOST_COMMENTS_OLD__C=Lost_Comments_OLD__c
```